# How to constantly recalculate a function who's main parameter is the current time

Tags: swift, function

I'm trying to calculate the satellite's orbital position and other data points as a function based on my current time. I currently have a class called Calculations with all my calculations including the main two functions keplerianElementsToECEF and ecefToData. In the view controller's view did load I input the 6 keplerian elements, epoch and the date of calculation (the current date). However while the calcualtiosn run and my table view displays the values accurately, the values don't update and the table view simply displays the calculations for the initial date at which the view did load. I'm almost certain the issue is caused by placing the date in the view controller's view did load, however I don't know how to work around this issue.

```
  var date = Date()
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    var dateAtCalculationAsString: String = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    // converting User's current time to UTC time to aid in computations
    let dateAtCalculation = localToUTC(date: dateAtCalculationAsString)
    print(dateAtCalculation)

    //let epoch = epoch, let inclination = inclination, let longitudeAscendingNode = longitudeAscendingNode, let eccentricity = eccentricity, let argumentPerigee = argumentPerigee, let meanAnomaly = meanAnomaly, let meanMotion = meanMotion {

    Calculations.shared.keplerianElementsToECEF(meanMotion: meanMotion!, eccentricity: eccentricity! , Inclination: inclination!, LongitudeAscendingNode: longitudeAscendingNode!, argumentPerigee: argumentPerigee!, M0: meanAnomaly!, epoch: epoch!, date: dateAtCalculation)


    datavalues = Calculations.shared.ecefToData()
```

Comment: Why are you converting the date to a string? Just work with `Date()`. That is the current date regardless of timezone.

Comment: so is that an issue or just something I should change?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to update something on a regular basis, or after some amount of time has passed, you can consider a [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer). Set up a new repeating Timer instance with a closure that updates your calculations, and then reloads your table.

For example, let's say that the code you posted is inside a function named `performCalculations()`. You could do something like:

```
var recalculateTimer: Timer!

func performCalculations() {
    // all the date math
}

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    performCalculations()
    recalculateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard let self = self else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }
        self.performCalculations()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This would re-run your math and update `datavalues` every second, then reload the table. It also stops the timer when your view controller deallocates, so if you dismiss a modal presentation containing this controller or pop it off a navigation stack, you won't be updating forever.